# Error 1004 When using MacroOption Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have an application in Access 2007 that is creating a workbook with ***N*** sheets i created a macro to be inserted into this workbook which works perfectly fine. But the next step is to add a Shortcut Key to the Marco so far i've seen to methods online to assist. The First attempt gives no errors but does not assign the shortcut key either

1) 
                       `Excel_App.OnKey "^{h}", "Sheet1.HideChange"`

2)`Excel_App.MacroOptions Macro:="Sheet1.HideChange", Description:="Hide Columns in Line Level", hasshortcutkey:=True, ShortcutKey:="h"`

My variables assigned to my method

```
Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks, wks2, wks3, wks4, wks5, wks6, wks7, wks8 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim xlmodule As Object 'VBComponent
Dim coaches As Recordset
Set Excel_App = New Excel.Application
Excel_App.Visible = False
Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks.Add
```

Below is where i last placed the shortcut, i've attempted to move the line of code before and after saving however i still get 1004 err.

```
    With wkb


             ActiveSheet.Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
            .Title = "CHANGE REQUEST"
            .Subject = "CHANGE REQUEST"

                      ' Add a macro to the module...
                     Dim strCode As String
                     strCode = _
                        "Sub HideChange()" & vbCr & _
                        "  Columns(""A:A"").Select Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True  " & vbCr & _
                        "end sub"
                    Dim module As VBComponent
                    Set module = wkb.VBProject.VBComponents(2)
                    module.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode
             Excel_App.MacroOptions Macro:="Sheet1.HideChange", Description:="Hide Columns in Line Level", hasshortcutkey:=True, ShortcutKey:="h"
            .SaveAs FileName:=strDir & "\CHANGE REQUEST FORM.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

            .Close
    End With

 Excel_App.Quit
```

Can anyone help me figure out how this works ? 
if you need more details to my question please ask, Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "Sheet1" from "Sheet1.HideChanges", it is not required (or correct).

[MacroOptions :MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838997.aspx)
[OnKey :MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx)